# Swap/Switch Android ActionBar items in onOptionsItemSelected method

Tags: android, android-actionbar, swap

How can I swap/switch between two `ActionBar` items?

I currently have two items in my action bar as indicated in the first image below - see the "grid" and the "timeline" icons.

I want to show only one and when the user touches  it, it should swap out with the other one. So say the grid item is showing, and the user touches it, the timeline item should show and the grid item should disappear. Like in the second image.

[image]

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work - no swapping is happening.

```
private static final int SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER = 0;
private static final int SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM = 1;
private static final int SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS = 2;

private Menu menu;
private MenuItem itemGrid;
private MenuItem itemTimeline;

//...

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar, m);

    menu = m;

    itemTimeline = menu.findItem(R.id.action_timeline);
    itemTimeline.setShowAsAction(SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem mi) {
    switch (mi.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_timeline:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Action grid selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        itemTimeline = menu.findItem(R.id.action_timeline);
        itemTimeline.setShowAsAction(SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);             

        itemGrid = menu.findItem(R.id.action_grid);
        itemGrid.setShowAsAction(SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        break;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Action settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

        default:
        break;
        }

    return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer tyczj, but I solved my problem by toggling the items' visibility like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar, m);             
    menu = m;

    itemTimeline = menu.findItem(R.id.action_timeline);
    itemGrid = menu.findItem(R.id.action_grid);     
    return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem mi) {
    switch (mi.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_timeline:                
        itemTimeline = menu.findItem(R.id.action_timeline);
        itemTimeline.setVisible(false);     

        itemGrid = menu.findItem(R.id.action_grid);
        itemGrid.setVisible(true);

        break;
    case R.id.action_grid:                
        itemTimeline = menu.findItem(R.id.action_timeline);
        itemTimeline.setVisible(true);  

        itemGrid = menu.findItem(R.id.action_grid);
        itemGrid.setVisible(false);

        break;              
    default:
    break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is invalidate the actionbar menu so that it is re-created using `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

this makes a call back to `onCreateOptionsMenu` to create the menu again.

what you will need is some sort of flag to know what menu to create

Answer (score 0):

use my toggle function :)

```
private Menu menu;
private boolean isGridtView

//----------------------------------

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
}

//-----------------------------------

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id){
        case R.id.action_change_layoutManager:
            // swap between two options
            toggle();
            return true;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}    

//---------------------------------- 

private void toggle() {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_change_layoutManager);
    if (!isGridtView) {
        // change layout manager type
        setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER);

        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_view_grid_24dp);
        isGridtView = true;
    } else {
        // change layout manager type
        setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType.GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER);

        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_view_list_24dp);
        isGridtView = false;
    }
}
```